# Structure of a RESTful API

Tags: api, rest

I want to build a RESTful API for my small project. There are three simple resources that I have:
 - Categories (id, title)
 - Posts (id, text, category_id)
 - Comments (id, text, post_id)

These are the end points that I need:

```
GET  /categories/                    => list of all categories
GET  /categories/:id/posts           => list of riddles in specified category
GET  /posts/:id                      => get single post
GET  /posts/:id/comments             => list of comments for specified post
GET  /comments/:id                   => get single comment
POST /posts/:id/comments             => create a comment (text comes from POST params)
```

Is this a good structure for API in this case?
Is this consider to be a RESTful API?

Comment: https://whizmodo.wordpress.com/2015/01/10/will-the-real-restful-api-please-stand-up/

Answer (score 3):

REST doesn't have anything to say about URI structure, so it's not really meaningful to ask if your endpoints are RESTful.

As far as the design, I would consider this instead:

```
GET /categories
GET /posts?categoryId=<categoryId>  -- or you could use category name, if the name is not the same as the id
GET /posts/<postId>
GET /comments?postId=<postId>
GET /comments/<commentId>
POST /comments
{ "postId" : 123, ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to REST, url should uniquely identify the resource which is happening in your case. As long as your url is Cacheable and you are using correct verbs and correct status codes, do not indulge in too much quabble about url structure. Additionally, you might want to look into 'Hypermedia', if you want your apis to be truly restful